# H27 error thrown when sending response back to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, async-await

I think this is probably a fairly simple fix, even though it's a lot of code...when the user starts loading into the app, it essentially sends a request to the server that calls a bunch of different APIs and sub functions, then returns some data queried from a Postgres table to the user. For some reason, About 40% of the time, I'm getting an H27 error thrown when the response is sent back to the user. The logs look like this:

```
2022-07-18T01:46:36.443368+00:00 app[web.1]: User is attempting to sign in
2022-07-18T01:46:36.443386+00:00 app[web.1]: Started processing
2022-07-18T01:46:36.883171+00:00 app[web.1]: Signing in from X,Y
2022-07-18T01:46:38.662059+00:00 app[web.1]: API Call 1,2,and 3
2022-07-18T01:46:40.416057+00:00 app[web.1]: API Call 4
2022-07-18T01:46:40.932732+00:00 app[web.1]: API Call 5
2022-07-18T01:46:40.949921+00:00 app[web.1]: API Call 6
2022-07-18T01:46:44.683997+00:00 app[web.1]: finished processing
2022-07-18T01:46:44.684014+00:00 app[web.1]: Sending 110 results back to the client
2022-07-18T01:46:44.694904+00:00 heroku[router]: sock=client at=warning code=H27 desc="Client Request Interrupted" method=POST path="/userLoadingInToApp" host=app-name.herokuapp.com request_id=11caaa97-4b27-431e-84bd-e8b82162877f fwd="xxx.xxx.xxx.xx" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8343ms status=499 bytes= protocol=https
```

I print out 'Sending x results back to the client' RIGHT before sending the results back to the client, so because the H27 error is thrown after that, it only makes sense there is an error being thrown when trying to send response back to the client:

```
app.post('/userLoadingInToApp', async function (request, response) {
  let results = await start(request) // All the calculations, database queries, api calls, console.logging etc are done inside this container function.
  console.log(`Sending ${results.length} back to the client`)
  response.send(results)
})
```

Often, the response is returned fine to the client, so not sure what's going on here...

Comment: Looks like processing the request takes too long and the client aborts. What's the request timeout you've configured on the client-side?

Comment: @eol I'm using URLSession through Swift, so whatever the default is for that. The request I posted above has a service time of 8.343 seconds if I'm reading it correctly, but I have other requests to this endpoint that have been successful where service=9640ms (9.64 seconds). Could this still be client timeout?

Comment: Hmm weird - as I don't know Swift I can only speculate but it looks like a client issue. Maybe you can try to manually increase the default timeout just for testing?

Comment: I can give it a shot, but that's a slow debug process, especially for not even knowing if that's the source of the issue (need to wait for App team approval)...

Comment: I'd usually use some automation tool to fire requests against the API-server. Or even try it manually first using e.g. Postman.

Comment: @eol If I use postman what do you recommend setting default client timeout to maybe 10 seconds and then seeing if the error is present and increasing it from there to see if it starts happening after that point?

Comment: I'd even go for a lower timeout (e.g. 3 seconds) just to check if you get the same H27 error and continue from there.

Comment: @eol So setting the timeout in Postman to 3 seconds DID throw the H27 error, and it sort of came out in the same exact logging order as above--the service number of the H27 error shows the amount of time it took for the entire request to complete, even if the client timed out beforehand. Does the 100% mean that the problem is a client-side timeout?

Comment: Certainly looks like it - maybe investigate further how `URLSession` deals with timeouts. Hope you find a solution :)